# Spurious change when using git diff <base>...<feature>

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Github seems to use the triple dot comparison on pull requests, which tricked me today by showing a spurious change between a feature and the base branch.

Here is the base branch (abbreviated):

```
git show upstream/develop:script.sql
 FOR field IN (
         [001*a], [001*d], [001*y], [001*x], [001*z],
         [004*a],
         [008*a], [008*d], [008*j], [008*l], [008*o],
         [009*a], [009*b], [009*g], [009*x], [009*u],
         [041*a], [041*c],
```

Here is the feature branch (abbreviated):

```
git show feature:script.sql
 FOR field IN (
         [001*a], [001*d], [001*y], [001*x], [001*z],
         [004*a],
         [008*a], [008*d], [008*j], [008*l], [008*o],
         [009*a], [009*b], [009*g], [009*x], [009*u],
         [041*a], [041*c],
```

Here is the output from a plain diff:

```
git diff upstream/develop feature script.sql
```

(No output.)

Here is the output from "changed on feature branch"-triple dot operator diff:

```
git diff upstream/develop...feature script.sql
  FOR field IN (
          [001*a], [001*d], [001*y], [001*x], [001*z],
+         [004*a],
          [008*a], [008*d], [008*j], [008*l], [008*o],
```

Why?

There is no change on this line. Adding `-w` shouldn't be necessary since the plain diff above was run without it and reported no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `git help diff`

> git diff [--options]   [--] [...]
>
> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary < commit >.
>
> ...
>
> git diff [--options] ... [--] [...]
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can omit any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD instead.
>
> ...
>
> However, "diff" is about comparing two endpoints, not ranges, and the range notations (".." and "...") do not mean a range as defined in the "SPECIFYING RANGES" section in git-rev-parse(1)

Assuming you have two branches

```
A-B-C-D (branch1)
   \
    E-F (branch2)
```

`git diff branch1 branch2 myfile` will give you a diff between the file content in D and F.

`git diff branch1...branch2` will give you  diff between the file content in B and F.

In your case the `[004*a],` may have been included in both branches, after B.